# Angular Compiler API replacement in Angular v13 for dynamic/runtime modules

Tags: angular, angular-compiler, angular13

We are using this function from the compiler [`compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync`](https://angular.io/api/core/Compiler#compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync) to create a *dynamic/runtime module*.

The compiler is [deprecated in Angular v13](https://angular.io/guide/deprecations#jit-api-changes).

Does anyone have a similar ( dynamic/runtime module ) use case and has successfully replaced the `Compiler` API?